# List comparison in C#

Tags: c#

I want to write a program,

-->If i  give the two paths that is path1 and path2.

-->Those need to compared and print the different(which are in path1 location and which are not there in path2 and vice versa also) folder and files.

-->I am using tow lists for folders and for files.

-->I am facing problem to compare two lists print the difference list.

How can i compare two list item and print the different item?

Comment: "I want to write a program, " - what's stopping you?

Comment: Show us what you've tried to do and we can give you help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var listA = new List<int> {1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 5, 3};
            var listB = new List<int> {4, 2, 7, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 1};

            var itemsInANotInB = listA.Except(listB).ToList();
            var itemsInBNotInA = listB.Except(listA).ToList();

            var listsHaveAllElementsInCommon = !(itemsInANotInB.Any() && itemsInBNotInA.Any());
            var listAreSequenceEqal = listA.SequenceEqual(listB);

            Console.WriteLine("Items in A but not in B: {0}", itemsInANotInB.Select(x=>x.ToString()).Aggregate((x,y) => x+", "+y));
            Console.WriteLine("Items in B but not in A: {0}", itemsInBNotInA.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x, y) => x + ", " + y));
            Console.WriteLine("A and B share the same elements? {0}", listsHaveAllElementsInCommon);
            Console.WriteLine("A and B are sequence-equal? {0}", listAreSequenceEqal);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's in your list? the objects has to be comparable by "equals" and maybe should implement IEquatable<T>.